# XNA - frequence of refreshing Draw/Update

Tags: c#, xna, draw

I am new in XNA programming, so it was sure I would have problems.

My problem is: when my player shoots a bullet from a gun, I count it's position change like this (in my void **Update()**):

```
Position.X += (float)Math.Cos(Angle) * Multiplier;
Position.Y += (float)Math.Sin(Angle) * Multiplier;
```

I think it's quite obvious. I got no problem with any directions, angles, etc. I am just curious how to refresh **Update** more frequently. I think that my **Multiplier** should be equal to 1 to make my bullet's move smooth. If I set my Multiplier to (for example) 50, my bullets is "jumping" - skipping every 50 * Cos/Sin pixels. When my bullet will "jump" like that, many object being between 2 calculated positions of bullet will avoid collision. Setting my **Multiplier** to "1" makes it very slow.

How to improve this thing? Is it necessary or am I just wrong?

Comment: You mean increasing your angle?
I mean, the multiplier just makes the distance bigger, not the steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the FixedTimeStep with [Game.TargetElapsedTime Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.targetelapsedtime.aspx) assuming that you're using Game.IsFixedTimeStep = true, but this probably won't speed you up too much, so you are going to need to have a Multiplier > 1 and then deal with possibilities of missing collisions at high speeds.

People counter this issue in various ways, such as casting rays from objects and detecting intersections of those paths before moving the objects themselves. It's an interesting problem, which comes up a lot. Forget the timestep, leave your multiplier at a suitable value to get the speeds you want, but search StackOverflow/the web for fast moving/small object collision detection.

Answer (score 0):

Your Update Methode should looks like this:

```
void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Position.X += (float)Math.Cos(Angle) * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    Position.Y += (float)Math.Sin(Angle) * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

You have to work with ElapsedGameTime to archive the same game-speed on different computers. Your game could run very fast on high-end computers if don't use the elapsedGameTime because the cpu has more power to call the update Methode. (Unit's run and shoot (or whatever they should do) fast on high-end computers)

You also have to use gameTime to create a playable multiplayer.

You shouldn't touch FixedTimeStep!

**- XNA call's the update methode as often as possible(depending on your hardware... max. 60 times per second with FixedTimeStep = true)!!**

(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds - This should return something around 16.667

if this is to much you have to decrease the value of your variable "Angle"